# Rearrange Bars in Bokeh Quad Chart

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

I'm trying to use the Bokeh Quad glyph to create a gantt chart and for some reason the bars are being added in reverse chronological order.

[Here is an image of the bokeh output that I'm getting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoAZz.png)

I am using a pandas dataframe to create a ColumnDataSource object, and no matter how I sort or reindex the dataframe it seems to have no effect on the layout of the Quad. I'd like for the bars to appear for activities sorted by start date and ascending, just like a normal gantt chart.

Is there a known way to reorganize the bars in the quad based on a source column?

For reference, here is the code that I'm using to generate the image linked above:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Range1d
from bokeh.models.tools import HoverTool
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

output_file('gantt_chart.html') 

data_dict = {'activityRef': ['c.001.50', 'c.002.51', 'c.073.51', 'c.074.51', 'c.003.52', 'c.004.53', 'c.079.53', 'c.080.53', 'c.005.54', 'c.084.54', 'c.006.60', 'c.088.61', 'c.091.61', 'c.092.61', 'c.007.61', 'c.093.61', 'c.094.61', 'c.095.61', 'c.096.62', 'm.003.62', 'c.008.62'], 'activityPrefix': ['Demolition', 'Grading', 'Structural Excavation, Backfill', 'MechElec Excavation, Backfill', 'Utilities', 'Civil Paving', 'Aggregates', 'Material Processing, Plants', 'Temporary Work', 'Scaffolding', 'Deep Foundation', 'Concrete Paving', 'Concrete Foundations', 'MechElec Concrete', 'Precast Concrete', 'Concrete Thermal Control', 'Rebar Placement', 'Anchor Bolts, Embedments', 'Structural Welding', 'Module Assembly', 'Erect Steel'], 'disciplineRef': ['Civil', 'Civil', 'Civil', 'Civil', 'Civil', 'Civil', 'Civil', 'Civil', 'Temporary Work', 'Temporary Work', 'Civil', 'Concrete', 'Concrete', 'Concrete', 'Concrete', 'Concrete', 'Concrete', 'Concrete', 'Structural', 'Structural', 'Structural'], 'duration': [10, 12, 18, 40, 25, 15, 10, 12, 18, 40, 25, 15, 10, 12, 18, 40, 25, 15, 10, 12, 18]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)

df['start'] = '6/16/2020'
df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start'])
df['start'] = [d + pd.Timedelta(days=i) for i, d in enumerate(df.start)]
df['end'] = df.apply(lambda row: row.start + pd.Timedelta(days=row.duration), axis=1)
df['color'] = 'blue'
df['activity'] = df.activityPrefix + ' - ' + df.activityRef
df['bottom'] = df.index+0.8
df['top'] = df.index+1.2


fig=figure(
    title='Project Schedule',
    x_axis_type='datetime',
    x_axis_location="above",
    width=1900,
    height=(df.shape[0] * 12),
    y_range=df.activity.tolist(),
    x_range=Range1d(df.start.min(), df.end.max()), 
)

hover=HoverTool(tooltips="Task: @activity<br>\
Start: @start<br>\
End: @end")
fig.add_tools(hover)

cds=ColumnDataSource(df)

fig.quad(left='end', right='start', bottom='bottom', top='top', source=cds, color="color")

show(fig)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried just inverting the data frame? I.e. sort its index in a descending order. If that doesn't work, please provide some test data so it's possible to run your example.

Comment: I added a few rows from the top of the df I'm using to the code above. I just tried sorting by index descending and that didn't do the trick unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution to my problem above: simply using the hbar glyph offers a correct alternative implementation:

```
fig.hbar(y='activity', height=0.5, left='end', right='start', source=cds, color="color")
```

Answer (score 0):

Reversing the order of your y_range should do the trick

```
y_range=df.activity.tolist()[::-1]
```